# Is there any way for one Arduino board to communicate with multiple sensors?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, iot

Say a home IoT application to monitor water levels in basement at 4 or 5 different places and transmit that data back to a single Arduino board to be then interfaced with a GUI to do home monitoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this could be done using SPI (with separate slave select wires), i2c or daisy chained UART providing a wired solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can ... however, how you transmit the sensor data? If wireless, you need some RF communication, and possibly a microcontroller like Arduino (or ESP) within each sensor module.

With nRF24L01 (2.4GHz) you can use 6 'slaves' (sensor modules in your case) to send data to the master (monitoring module).

Do things one by one:

- First make one sensor module
- Than make the master to receive data
- Than make the GUI screen
- Than make the other five sensor modules